# How to mention the magento version compatibility in composer.json

Tags: module, magento2.2, composer

I am creating a module in Magento 2. Now I am writing composer.json. Here I write supporting PHP version

```
"require": {
    "php": "~5.6.0|^7.0.0",
  },
```

How do I write my module will be supported by Magento version greater than 2.1, not support by 2.0

I found

```
 "magento/framework": "^102.0.0",
"magento/module-backend": "^101.0.0"
```

What is the meaning of above lines . is it the version of Magento?
what are 102.0.0 means?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot specify a version for the 'parent' project in general with composer. The [version](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#version) of a composer package (here the Magento shop) is even optional, so you could not reliably depend on it:

> The version of the package. In most cases this is not required and should be omitted

And a Magento installation is consisting of Magento modules. And these modules have their own versions. Though it would desirable to tell composer "Hey, this module can only be used with version X of Magento", you actually have to make the extension dependent on the other Magento extensions, which seems to have their own versioning scheme (with versions > 100). And probably this is what you actually want, since (I guess) your module code really depends on those Magento core modules.

In the composer.json file of my installation (2.3.1) I found a required package `"magento/product-community-edition":"2.3.1"`. It would be tempting to make the module dependent on this, however, this is [discouraged](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/versioning/dependencies.html):

> Do not specify a dependency on meta packages (e.g. product-community-edition).

So it seems you should make your module open for different versions or specify the requirements in a readme file.

Comment: Regarding `"magento/product-community-edition"` I created an [issue](https://github.com/magento/devdocs/issues/4278) for the docs.